# Отправка автоматически уведомлений на почту. PHP

Tags: php, битрикс

Пробую создать функцию автоматической отправки уведомлений на почту клиента при истечении срока созданного им объявления.
Поле даты истечения срока объявления `$arLot['PROPERTY_VALUES']['PRIK']['VALUE']`
Вот код который я пытаюсь внедрить:

```
function SendMAil($arFields){
if ($arFields['IBLOCK_ID'] == "14") {

    $arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "PROPERTY_*");
    $arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID" => $arFields['IBLOCK_ID'], "ID" => $arFields['ID']);
    $res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);
    while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()){
        $arField = $ob->GetFields();
        $arProps = $ob->GetProperties();
        $arField['PROPERTY_VALUES'] = $arProps;
        $arLot = $arField;
    }

    $SANDMAIL = false;
    if (MakeTimeStamp(date('d.m.Y H:i:s'))+7*24*60*60 >= MakeTimeStamp($arLot['PROPERTY_VALUES']['PRIK']['VALUE'])*1 )
        {
         $SANDMAIL = true;
        }
    }

    if ($SANDMAIL) {
        $useEmail = array();
        foreach ($arFields['PROPERTY_VALUES']['30'] as $valUses) {
            if ($valUses['VALUE']) {
                CModule::IncludeModule("main");
                $rsUser = CUser::GetByID($valUses['VALUE']);
                $arUser = $rsUser->Fetch();
                $useEmail[] = $arUser['EMAIL'];
            }
        }
        if ($arFields['PROPERTY_VALUES']['3']['n0']['VALUE']) {
            foreach ($useEmail as $email) {
                $arEventFields = array('NAME' => $arFields['NAME'], 'EMAIL' => $email, 'ID_ELEMENT' => $arFields['ID'], 'DATA_TO' => $arFields['PROPERTY_VALUES']['3']['n0']['VALUE']);
                CEvent::Send("date_changes", "s1", $arEventFields, "Y", 30);
            }

        }
    }
 }
```

Вся проблема думаю в условии `if (MakeTimeStamp(date('d.m.Y H:i:s'))+7*24*60*60 >= MakeTimeStamp($arLot['PROPERTY_VALUES']['PRIK']['VALUE'])*1 )` как правильно поставить условие **если текущая дата больше или равна даты которая берется из поля**??

Comment: 1. Все таки не `$SANDMAIL`, а `$SENDMAIL` )). 2. Зачем последнюю дату умножаете на 1? 3. Вы пробовали тестировать код? Например, `echo 1` до и после условия?

Comment: А что конкретно у вас отправляется в сообщении?
Можно увидеть полный код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для проверки можно использовать:

```
$date_to_check = new DateTime($arLot['PROPERTY_VALUES']['PRIK']['VALUE']);
$now = new DateTime(); // время сейчас   
if ( ($now->getTimestamp() + 7*24*60*60) >= $date_to_check->getTimestamp()) {
  // тут Ваш код
}
```

Я попробовал - у меня работает проверка. Надеюсь, что и  Вам поможет :)